# Getting current revision from SVN before compiling in xCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, svn, run-script

i'm trying to get the current SVN version before compilation, but xCode(5.1) start compiling files before running the custom shell scripts.

to get the SVN revision i follow this [example](http://getsetgames.com/2009/10/21/automatically-insert-your-svn-revision-number-into-your-xcode-project/):

i add a run script which get the current revision and insert it in the `revision.h` file but this must be before compile:

```
REV=`svnversion -n`
echo "#define kRevision @\"$REV\"" > ${PROJECT_DIR}/revision.h
```

1. How can i run this script before compile.
2. Is there an other what to get the current SVN version and use it at application run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed this (sorry to answer to my own question)

the problem was very simple : i was modifying the cote " ` " by " ' ".